# Prove that $n(n-1)<3^n$ for all $n≥2$ By induction

Tags: inequality, induction

Prove that $n(n-1)<3^n$ for all $n≥2$. By induction.
What I did:

Step 1- Base case: 
Keep n=2

$2(2-1)<3^2$

$2<9$ Thus it holds.

Step 2- Hypothesis:

Assume: $k(k-1)<3^k$

Step 3- Induction: 
We wish to prove that:

$(k+1)(k)$<$3^k.3^1$

We know that $k≥2$, so $k+1≥3$

Then $3k<3^k.3^1$

Therefore, $k<3^k$, which is true for all value of $n≥k≥2$

Is that right? Or the method is wrong? Is there any other methods?

Comment: Yes, this is right. (But in the last line $k\ge2$, or use $n$ everywhere.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust, look more closely at what the OP is doing in Step 3.  He's actually assuming what he wants to prove when he says "Then $3k\lt 3^k.3^1$" (i.e., $k+1\ge3$ implies $3k\le(k+1)k\lt3^k.3^1$).

Comment: @BarryCipra: you are quite right, I didn't see that. Actually the induction hypothesis is used nowhere. He should have said $k(k-1)<3^k\implies k(k+1)<3^k+2k<3.3^k$ and proven $k<3^k$.

Answer (score 5):

We know that  $k(k-1)<3^k$ (The induction assumption)

Multiply 3 both sides, and we get:

$3k(k-1)<3^{k + 1}$

Now we will be done if we prove that 
 $k(k+1)\le3k(k - 1)$.

This can be rearranged as  $2k - 4 \ge 0$, which is true since $k \ge 2$.

Hence proved.

Answer (score 2):

Other approach (not induction): by the binomial theorem,
$$(1+2)^n=1+n.2+\frac12n(n-1).2^2+\frac1{3!}n(n-1)(n-2).2^3\cdots>n(n-1).$$

Answer (score 1):

I think that your solution is fine. However, I would phrase it slightly different.

Step-2. To be completely formal, I would say: Let $k>2$ and assume $k(k-1)<3^k$.

Step 3. We need to show $k(k+1)<3^{k+1}$. We have $$k(k+1)=k(k-1)+2k<3^k+2k<3^k+3^k+3^k=3^{k+1}$$
Where we have used the inductive hypothesis and the fact that $k<3^k$, which is true because $k>2$.

Notice that you can prove that the inequality is true for all $n\geq0$ (indeed the base case will become trivial!).